# Accessing GitHub using NPM on Sonatype Nexus

Tags: github, npm, nexus

We're currently using Nexus 2.10, and have successfully used it as a repo for npm.

Building locally through this proxy/mirror works fine, but when trying to run `npm install` on Bamboo (which doesn't have internet access), it fails, as some dependency tries to reach GitHub to download something, which fails.

```
error   06-feb-2015 13:29:29    npm http 200 https://nexus.shdir.no/content/groups/npm-all/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.0.tgz
error   06-feb-2015 13:29:30    npm http GET https://nexus.shdir.no/content/groups/npm-all/formidable
error   06-feb-2015 13:29:30    npm http 200 https://nexus.shdir.no/content/groups/npm-all/formidable
error   06-feb-2015 13:29:45    npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/rase-/node-XMLHttpRequest/archive/a6b6f2.tar.gz
error   06-feb-2015 13:29:55    npm http GET https://github.com/rase-/node-XMLHttpRequest/archive/a6b6f2.tar.gz
error   06-feb-2015 13:30:16    npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/rase-/node-XMLHttpRequest/archive/a6b6f2.tar.gz
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:16    npm http GET https://github.com/rase-/node-XMLHttpRequest/archive/a6b6f2.tar.gz
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:37    npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/rase-/node-XMLHttpRequest/archive/a6b6f2.tar.gz
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:38    npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:38    npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:38    npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:38    npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:38    npm ERR! network 
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:38    npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:38    npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:38    
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:38    npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:38    npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:38    npm ERR! cwd E:\bamboo\UTV-FP-JOB1\code
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:38    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.17
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:38    npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.8
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:38    npm ERR! syscall connect
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:38    npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
error   06-feb-2015 13:31:38    npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
```

How would I go about this problem? Do I have to add every repo from github/bitbucket to Nexus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved the problem by downloading the binaries manually, and adding them to our Apache server. Won't be fun when updating dependencies, but shouldn't be too bad. Only 3 files.

I'd be happy to use a better solution, if anyone knows of one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make Nexus available to your Bamboo server and configure npm there just like you did on your workstation. Depending on where Bamboo and Nexus are installed in terms of network topology that might require different steps.

Ideally your repository manager and your CI server are co-located and a high performance connection to each other. This allows for fast downloads of proxied packages as well fast deployments.

You can for example make your Nexus available on the public internet and lock it down to allow only authenticated access and then use it like that from Bamboo.

Comment: Nexus is available, the packages located at npm's repo are reachable just fine from Bamboo. It's the direct http calls to Github that implodes. Is it possible to say e.g. all https requests to github and bitbucket can go right through? To give full access to the net is probably a no-go, although I haven't been able to ask about it yet. And locally we have full access to the internet.